# How can I make these three statements more secure against SQL injection?

Tags: c#, php

### 1.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con)
  {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("jbell2", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO Profile (username, Date, Height, Weight, WaistSize, WeightforHeight, Blood_Pressure, Medication, Total_Cholesterol, Bad_Cholesterol, Good_Cholesterol, Triglycerides,KidneyFunctionTest)
VALUES 

('$_Post[username]', '$_POST[Date]', '$_POST[Height]', '$_POST[Weight]', '$_POST[WaistSize]','$_POST[WeightforHeight]', '$_POST[Blood_Pressure]','$_POST[Medication]' ,'$_POST[Total_Cholesterol]' ,'$_POST[Bad_Cholesterol]' ,'$_POST[Good_Cholesterol]','$_POST[Triglycerides]','$_POST[KidneyFunctionTest]' )";
```

### 2

.

```
          MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host="";user="";password=""; database="";");
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Patients(username, password, FirstName, SecondName, DiabetesType, Email,Phone, Phone2, Question1, Question2,TreatmentPlan)"
+ "values" + "('" + uname.Text + "','" + password.Text + "','" + fname.Text + "','" + lname.Text + "','" + Dtype.Text + "','" + email.Text + "','" + phone.Text + "','" + phone2.Text + "','" + q1.Text + "','" + q2.Text + "','" + treatment.Text + "')");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

Comment: Quite frankly, this looks like homework or an interview question.

Comment: Someone with more PHP-fu can correct me if I'm wrong (some way to misuse `echo` to execute arbitrary code? :P), but the first snippet appears pretty safe from SQL injection to me. You know, insofar as it doesn't *interact with a database*...

Comment: `"INSERT INTO Students(name) values (" + "Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--" + ")"`

Comment: @yes123 have you just lolled me? :/

Comment: @justin morgan, its not homework for your information. Its a personal project that I am doing in my own time to improve my skills. I dont not much or even anything about sql injection  so i am asking for some simple advice, i dont see what the problem is with that?

Comment: @Joe - No problem with that, and homework questions aren't necessarily against the rules. I was curious because there were snippets in two different languages doing essentially the same thing, so it seemed unlikely to be production code. Glad you got the answers you needed. You may find http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C# portion:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Patients (username, password, FirstName, 
//...
+ "values" + "('" + uname.Text + "','" + password.Text + "','" + fname.Text + "','" +  
//...
+ "')");
```

These values should be passed in as parameters. Your command text should be built like this:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Patients (username, password, FirstName, 
//...
+ "values (@username, @password, @FirstName, 
//...
+ "')");
```

Under that, you should have something like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", uname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", password.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", fname.Text);
//...
```

If you don't, you're asking for a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Dunno about PHP but in `C#` you can use Parameters instead of directly injecting the values.

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host="";user="";password=""; database="";"))
{
    con.Open();
    string strSQL = "INSERT INTO Patients(username, password, FirstName, SecondName, DiabetesType, Email,Phone, Phone2, Question1, Question2,TreatmentPlan) values (?name, ?password, .....)";
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, con))
    {
        cmd.Parametrs.AddWithValue("?name", fname.Text);
        cmd.Parametrs.AddWithValue("?password", lname.Text);
        ..........
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Just have `?` followed by some identifier to mark that you add parameter, then use `AddWithValue` to insert the real value.
Also showing how to use `using` which dispose of the objects properly.

Answer (score 2):

In first you don't have any word in `SQL` language.

In 2 and 3 you are creating `SQL Query` by concating string, this is wrong; in 2 you can use `PDO` to prepare `PDOStatement` object and execute it passing arguments securely, in second you can probably prepare this query and pass arguments but must read documentation how do this.

Read this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Answer (score 2):

for option 2.  you should definately be real escaping your strings at minimum before inserting in to DB with mysql_real_escape_string().

and you should always validate your data before inserting in to db. check you are getting the data you want, and replace any chars you should be getting.